# Safari 6: redirect not working when form action has been altered by Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, safari

### Context

I have a form on each picture that has 'action' attribute to redirect to the current url.
I want that after having submitted the form, the user is redirected to the current url followed by the hash of the picture he was commenting on.

### What I want

- **'old'** action attribute of the form = **?q=page/35**
- **'new'** action attribute of the form = **?q=page/35#4**

### What I did

**Javascript:**

```
var oldFormAction = $('span').find('.replies-form').attr('action');
if (!oldfFormAction.match(/#/)){
    $('span').find('.replies-form').prop('action', oldFormAction + location.hash)
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="image-caption current" style="opacity: 1;">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="reply-add-form" class="replies-form" method="post" action="?q=page/35">
        <div>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</span>
```

### What is not working

- In **Chrome & Firefox**, it works as expected!
- However, in **Safari 6** (didn't test on IE), the hash is **not kept during the form submission**, even though the **form action itself changes** (line 3 of the above code).

Comment: Post the HTML involved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pointy. It is now in my updated question.

Comment: Hmm ... well that seems simple enough (other than the issue that a block-level element like `<form>` shouldn't really be in a `<span>`, but that won't hurt anything about form submission). How can you tell that the hash is lost? Is there an element on the page whose "id" is "4"? Or does the hash just not shown in the URL?

Comment: Also I apologize for my gruff tone in that original comment; I wasn't angry or upset so I don't know why I wrote it like that :-)

Comment: No worry about the tone Pointy, my fault I didn't post the HTML first ;-)
I can tell the hash is lost because when my form is submitted, the user should be redirected to `?q=page/35#4`. It works in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari, it only redirects to `?q=page/35`.

Comment: After your comment, I verified if the `action` attribute was actually set with the hash in Safari and even though I couldn't access it through Firebug Lite HTML, I used `console.log($('span').find('.replies-form').attr('action'))` and it returned the correct URL: `?q=page/35#4` so it is well set there. This is confirmed: the issue appears when submitting the form... Pretty weird!